# Is there a way to view everything that is queued in the JavaScript runloop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, google-chrome-devtools, q

My frontend application makes heavy use of asynchronous operations wrapped in Q Promises. I am trying to figure out from a high level in what sequence different promises are resolving.

I have one promise in particular, and sometimes it resolves immediately - in such instances it's `then` function is invoked on the next tick of the JavaScript runloop - but for some reason it randomly takes longer to queue in JavaScript runloop despite the data always being available.

Is there an extension/tool/resource/possibility to view everything that is queued in the JavaScript runloop?